# В чем различие между OpenGL, DirectX, OpenCL, CUDA?

Tags: opengl, directx, cuda, opencl

сразу прошу прощение за очень глупый вопрос, но чем отличается OpenСL от DirectX, OpenGL, CUDA? почему есть сравнение DirectX с OpenGL и OpenCL с CUDA, но нет сравнения допустим OpenCL и DirectX? я догадываюсь что они очень разные, но как я понимаю они все позволяют обращаться к видеокарте и ускорять с помощью нее вычисления. Хотелось бы узнать различие между этими технологиями и что за что отвечает?

Comment: А как вы собираетесь сравнивать сладкое и зелёное?

Comment: @ArchDemon По идее они не являются "сладким или зеленым", по факту это API для доступа к ресурсам видеокарты. Если бы один обращался к видеокарте, второй к звуковой карте, третий к сетевым параметрам тогда я бы понял что нельзя их сравнивать, но тут все они обращаются к видеокарте и делают на ней просчеты, значит сравнить их можно по скорости работы и применению в разных сферах и где какая технология предпочтительней.

Comment: Для начала: OpenGL и DirectX предназначены для работы с графикой, а CUDA и OpenCL  - для распараллеливания на GPU. Т.е эти внутри этих пар их можно как-то сравнивать, но между - нет.

Comment: То что сладкое и зелёное принадлежит моему яблоку, ещё не значит эти характеристики можно сравнивать между собой

Comment: @ArchDemon можно ли с помощью каждой технологии сделать подсчеты с графикой? Если да, то вполне можно сравнить или все таки расписать в чем принципиальное их отличие, где используется одна технология, а где другая. Если обратиться к википедии и сравнить directX и openCL то область применения у них попадает на графику, встает вопрос когда рационально использовать одно а когда другое.

Comment: CUDA и OpenCL занимаются параллельными вычислениями. Где вы здесь увидели слово "графика"? Общего у перечисленных вами терминов только одно - видеокарта

Comment: @ArchDemon тогда возникает вопрос если они все таки разные, то могут ли работать совместно?

Comment: В каком плане совместно? Например, вы можете рисовать графику в DirectX, а физику объектов считать в CUDA. И всё это будет в одной программе. Достаточно совместно?

Comment: @ArchDemon если такая связка работает то хотелось бы узнать насколько рационально считать физику на видеокарте?

Comment: @ИльяАнтипанов NVIDIA PhysX считает физику как раз на видеокарте, так что видимо рационально

Comment: Все вычисления, которые можно распараллелить, рационально считать на видеокарте. Это даже настолько рационально, что существуют гибридные суперкомпьютеры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## OpenGL vs DirectX

Это два движка для отрисовки графики.

DirectX - это только для Windows, с C++ и интерфейсами, с закрытым кодом.

OpenGL открытый, есть для многих разных платформ. Внутри код написан в Си стиле.

В принципе любая игра может быть написана на любой из платформ. Да, на них можно сделать расчеты, но неудобно.

## OpenCL vs CUDA

А это средства, которые позволяют использовать видеокарту для рассчётов. В первом приближении можно считать, что видеокарта это много-много маленьких процессоров, которые умеют выполнять однотипные расчеты.

CUDA - разработка от Nvidia. Закрытые исходники, только для Nvidia.
OpenCL - открытое, для разнообразных видеокарт.

Писать на них игры можно, конечно, но эти библиотеки (или это все таки фреймворки?) не предназначены для отрисовки графики.

Comment: *"только, с с++ и интерфейсами"* - с С интерфейсом, как другие COM API. OpenGL на некоторых платформах уже приказал долго жить, и практически везде требует использования различных специфических расширений (костылей)

Comment: не знаю, opengl живет весело. И работает хорошо.

Comment: @KoVadim говорят, Apple выпиливает OpenGL на своих устройствах :(

Comment: да, пытаются сделать свой metal. На линуксе, на телефонах пока похоже никто даже трогать не будет.

Comment: А на телефонах его и не было, там OpenGL ES + свои наборы костылей.

Comment: я так понимаю, в Вашем понимании, любой OpenGl - это OpenGL с костылями?

Comment: Да, в OpenGL без костылей - никуда.